# How to update objects in core data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I want to update my core-data entity and my code is:

```
let ff: Cart!
let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow
ff = self.cart[indexPath!.row]

let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = app.managedObjectContext

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Cart", inManagedObjectContext: context)
let cartt = Cart(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
cartt.name = ff.name
cartt.price = Double(ff.price!)
cartt.rest_id = ff.rest_id
cartt.longg = ff.longg
cartt.latt = ff.latt
cartt.item_id = ff.item_id
cartt.restName = ff.restName
cartt.cookTime = ff.cookTime

ff.setValue(Int(txt.text!), forKey: "quantity")

do{
    try context.save()
    self.viewDidLoad()
    print(cartt.longg)
    print(cartt.delivery)
    print("saved")

}catch{
    print("could not save")
}
```

The element is updating in the core data, but it is also adding a new row to my `tableView` with an empty data.

Comment: why you called `self.viewDidLoad()` after saving data ?

Comment: To re calculate the cart

Comment: you want to update only `quantity ` value, right ?

Comment: Yes @Chetankasundra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update `quantity` of the current object `ff` try with these lines.

```
        let ff: Cart!
        let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow
        ff = self.cart[indexPath!.row]
        let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = app.managedObjectContext
        ff.setValue(Int(txt.text!), forKey: "quantity")
        do{
            try context.save()
            self.viewDidLoad() // why you call this line here ?
            print(cartt.longg)
            print(cartt.delivery)
            print("saved")
        }catch{
            print("could not save")
        }
```

Why did you call `self.viewDidLoad()`?

On your next code, you was creating a new item rather than just updating the current one.

Comment: To calculate the cart again that is multiply the change quantity by the price

Comment: Ok it is working now but i need to update the view when it is changed

Comment: Ok perfect ! ;) But it's not recommended to call directly `viewDidLoad:` may be you should refactor a little bit